# S3 hive external table on subdirectories is not working

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, hiveql, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I have following s3 directory structure.

```
Data/
   Year=2015/
         Month=01/
            Day=01/
                files
            Day=02/
                files
         Month=02/
            Day=01/
                files
            Day=02/
                files
         .
         .
         .

   Year=2014/
         Month=01/
            Day=01/
                files
            Day=02/
                files
         Month=02/
            Day=01/
                files
            Day=02/
                files
```

So i am creating hive external table as follow

```
CREATE external TABLE trips
(
 trip_id  STRING,probe_id STRING,provider_id STRING,
 is_moving TINYINT,is_completed BOOLEAN,start_time STRING,
 start_lat  DOUBLE,start_lon DOUBLE,start_lat_adj DOUBLE) 
  PARTITIONED BY (year INT,month INT,day INT)
  STORED AS TEXTFILE
  LOCATION 's3n://accesskey:secretkey@bucket/data/';
```

When i run query on this table no data is returned without any exception. If i place same files in one directory only and without partitioning, then it runs fine. I also tried bey setting

```
set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
```

Any idea where i am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `ALTER TABLE trips RECOVER PARTITIONS` command. This command will create metadata for table partitions which exist in S3. See docs here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)